# Finding "optional codes" using apt-get (17.10)

Tags: apt

I want to install code that has optional support code. In prior versions of Ubuntu, I could view those support code options in a software installer app, like the Ubuntu Software app available now - but more general.

I have Canonical Partners checked in Software & Updates, but cannot find several codes I want; e.g., gfortran, paraview, vmtools . . .

So, if I want to install a code using "sudo apt-get install paraview" (say), is there a way to get a list of support codes (oe code options) for the target code? (paraview, paraview-dev, paraview-doc,paraview-python, libxdmf3 . . . )

I can get a list using apt-cache search, but I don't know how to install what code(s) I want.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: You may want to try to search "codes" from Muon (`sudo apt-get install muon`).

Comment: Could you [add](https://askubuntu.com/posts/984146/edit) the output of  `sudo apt-get install paraview`? And clarify what you mean by "cannot find several codes". Do you meen you can't install `paraview` or you can't install packages `paraview` depends/recomends/suggests?

Comment: @J.Starnes Thank you. I installed paraview. But: I meant that I could not tell what codes might be recommended to be installed along with paraview. I got answers that dealt with the specific question of "other suggested codes" via apt-get. Those suggested codes are names, and so it is not as convenient as the old software installer - on which those suggested codes were described (a little).

Answer (score 1):

There are three levels of dependencies.

**Depends**: Package A absolutely must have this package installed.
**Recommends**: Package A should also have this package for the common use of Package A.
**Suggests**: Package A is usually enhanced by suggested package.

`apt-get` defaults to installing depends and recommended packages. To also install suggested packages run `apt-get --install-suggests install gfortran`

To list a synpackages dependencies , run `apt-cache depends <package>` from the command line.

```
apt-cache depends gfortran
gfortran
  Depends: cpp
  Depends: gcc
  Depends: gfortran-5
  Suggests: gfortran-multilib
  Suggests: gfortran-doc
```

A gui method would use `synaptic` package manager. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1hDW.png)